# Adding 'jump to' link to specific section in the page inside search result description

Tags: seo, google, web-development, search-results

I've noticed Wikipedia has many direct links to specific sections in their pages in search results descriptions. For example when searching for 'stackoverflow history wikipedia' the first result that comes up is the stackoverflow page along with a direct link to that specific section in the page ('history') with a 'jump to' link. [this search on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow%20wikipedia&aq=f&oq=stackoverflow%20wikipedia&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=stackoverflow%20history%20wikipedia&oq=stackoverflow%20history%20wikipedia&gs_l=serp.3...6033.6830.0.7137.8.7.0.0.0.5.397.2012.2-4j3.7.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.cPM3daN23mk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45373924,d.bGE&fp=c0f615c147904ef0&biw=1246&bih=694) How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those links are generated automatically. You can't *explicitly* tell Google to produce them, but can increase your chances by creating descriptively-named internal anchors on long pages and producing a "table of contents" block linking to them. I don't have a documentation page right at hand, but the [announcement post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-named-anchors-to-identify.html) for the feature has a bit of information.

Comment: thx seems helpful. btw you're profile link notedwithout.com has syntax error.