# How to get site links for a non branded search query in google SERP?

Tags: search-results, sitelinks

Ive noticed when searching for "SERVICE + LOCATION" in google on a phone / table (not yet on desktop) some results will get Site links even though the search query wasn't specifically for them.

Eg. In the below screenshot i searched for "Car rental in London". Notice how Sixt has these site links on their SERP listing.

How can you get these for a site ? Im familiar with seeing them as site links if you search for a brand, but not for a "SERVICE + LOCATION" query.

[image: screenshot from mobile SERP results]

Answer (score 3):

[Google display anchor links from a section of webpage](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/using-named-anchors-to-identify.html), if it is well formatted.

So that page contain jump links (`/united-kingdom/london#traffic-information`) with proper section, hence Google display it.

Google display so many things other than only webpage title, link and description. It now also display [table data](http://www.thesempost.com/google-showing-tables-regular-search-results/), [mini data about company](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/47496/58259)  and [forum links](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/96617/58259).